# Sentence starting with "With"

Tags: prepositions, structure

I am having trouble understanding the grammar of the below sentence that starts with "with".

> **With** back-to-back matches against Shakhtar Donetsk to come, Real Madrid cannot afford any more slip-ups.

What is the structure of such usage of "with"? I would have rather used the below sentence to convey the same meaning.

> As back-to-back matches against Shakhter Donestsk are incoming, Real Madrid cannot afford any more slip-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special construction where **with** marks a verbless absolute clause modifying the main clause. To take the example in the previous answer:

- *With so many people ill*, the meeting was cancelled.

This is equivalent to:

- ***Given that** so many people **were** ill*, the meeting was cancelled.

The sentence from your question:

- *With back-to-back matches against Shakhtar Donetsk to come*, Real Madrid cannot afford any more slip-ups.

I would paraphrase that as

- ***Given that** back-to-back matches against Shakhtar Donetsk **are** to come*

meaning the matches are upcoming (will happen soon).

Answer (score 1):

According to "Advanced Grammar in use", "With" can be used followed by a noun phrase to give a reason, consider the following example:

> With so many people ill, the meeting was cancelled (== as a result of there being)