# What is the name of this structure and more information please

Tags: grammar

I have been encountering the same sentence structure a few times recently but I do not know its name. So I would like to know the name of this structure in English grammar and have more information about it. Here is one of the sentences I met:

*California has been facing a drought for many years now, **with certain areas even having to pump freshwater hundreds of miles to their distribution system.***

The part that I have problem with is in **bold**.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's a "whole sentence adverbial phrase". For a "single-word" whole sentence adverb, consider ***Worryingly**, California has been facing a drought for many years now* (whole sentence adverbs can come before or after the sentence/clause they modify; it's just more idiomatic in this *specific* case to put ***worryingly*** at the front). For a "single verb" adverb, consider *California has been **bravely** facing a drought for many years now.* For a shorter "with" adverbial element to clarify the usage, *California has been facing a drought for many years now, **with stoicism***.

Comment: (That final example would normally have the adverbial element closer to the verb phrase it modifies: *California has been facing a drought with stoicism for many years now*.)

Comment: It is a special use of "with" marking an absolute clause. [This post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298897/sentence-starting-with-with/299054) is related.